# ¿Como acceder a los elementos de un Arraylist de arrays?

Tags: c#, array, arraylist

¿Como podría acceder a este tipo de arraylist?

```
List<String[]> arraylist1= new List<String[]>;
String[] splits = Str.Split(';');
```

La duda es, ¿como puedo hacer para obtener la información de la segunda posición del array?

```
_____________________
|List<String[]>      |
|____________________|
|[0]                 |
|____________________|
|   [0]"Juan"        |
|   [1]"Garcia"      |
|   [2]"Lorca"       |
|____________________|
|[1]                 |
|____________________|
|   [0]"Pepe"        |
|   [1]"Apellido"    |
|   [2]"Apellido2"   |
|                    |
|____________________|
```

Como ejemplo simple, digamos que luego quiero hacer algo del tipo:

```
Console.Write(Arraylist1[0][1]);
```

Comment: Y cual es el problema con `Arraylist1[0][1]`? Te lanza algun error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo puedes hacer de la siguiente manera:

```
Arraylist.ElementAt(0)[1]  //Con Arraylist.ElementAt(0) tenemos el primer elemento de la lista y con [1] accedemos al apellido
```

O también lo puedes hacer de esta manera si lo que quieres es recorrer el listado

```
foreach(String[] s in Arraylist)
{
    Console.Write(s[1]);  //s es el elementpo de la lista en el que estemos en cada iteración, [1] es el apellido
}
```

Comment: Al final me ha funcionado con `ArrayList[1][1]` pero dejo esto como válido para quien no le funcione. Gracias. 

Tenía asignado un string en vez de un String[] a la lista.

Comment: Ok, había pensado como @Einer, que te debería haber funcionado (como al final pasa) pero como no me gusta acceder a los elementos de una lista como un array te he puesto estas opciones.

Comment: Se agradece siempre para poder conocer más formas, gracias.